# For one terrible moment there, I was afraid it had [killed you]

Tags: past-perfect, prepositional-phrases

> “You got there?[= London] You got Hermione’s owl?” 
>    “We must
>   have crossed in midair. No sooner had I reached London than it became
>   clear to me that the place I should be was the one I had just left. I
>   arrived just in time to pull Quirrell off you.” 
>    “It was you.”
>   
>    “I feared I might be too late.” 
>    “You nearly were, I
>   couldn’t have kept him off the Stone much longer –” 
>    “Not the
>   Stone, boy, you — the effort involved nearly killed you. **For one
>   terrible moment there, I was afraid it had**. As for the Stone, it has
>   been destroyed.” 
>    “Destroyed?” said Harry blankly. “But your
>   friend — Nicolas Flamel —” 
>    “Oh, you know about Nicolas?” said
>   Dumbledore, sounding quite delighted. “You did do the thing properly,
>   didn’t you? Well, Nicolas and I have had a little chat, and agreed
>   it’s all for the best.” 
>    “But that means he and his wife will
>   die, won’t they?” 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

The sentence is confusing me in three points: (1) what does ‘for’ mean? : it seems that without ‘for’, the phrase can denote the reason of the next clause. (2) which is there?: London, where Harry is struggling with Quirrell, or the situation Harry had to undergo on his own. (3) if ‘for one terrible moment there’ is a condition, there didn’t happened the incident worried yet. Then why is there past perfect, had?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is not a subordinate clause but an ordinary adverbial of time: *for [time expression]* is roughly equivalent to *during [time expression]*.
2. *There* is being used of the situation, the time-and-place when Dumbledore arrived and pulled Quirrell off of Harry.
3. Past perfect is used because Dumbledore is referring to the effort which almost killed Harry [Event Time] before Dumbledore arrived [Reference Time].

So the sentence means "[When I arrived] I was afraid, for a brief but terrible moment, that the effort had [killed you]."